# Парсинг сложной структуры Json

Tags: java, json

Приветствую, коллеги.
Есть задача: от доп. системы приходит json с сегментами, в которые входит пользователь. Нужно вытащить из него все сегменты, в которые входит этот пользователь и дальше проверять.
От доп. системы приходит такого вида json:

```
{'response':{
     '12345': [
          {'22':'data'}
              ]
}}
```

Вся проблема в том, что то, что приходит под ключом 12345 - динамическое значение, соответственно, может знает кто-нибудь либы для того, чтобы двигаться по json как по дереву с родителями и чилдренами, чтобы не быть привязанным к ключам?

Comment: Двигаться по ключам не обязательно, т.к. json обычно после сериализации описывается структурами: список и словарь, а у словарей кроме доступа по ключам, можно получить все ключи, или просто итератором пройтись по всем элементам словаря

Comment: Это понятно, но вопрос то в другом, мне ради получения вот этих самых сегментов нужно рекурсивно проверять каждый массив на уровне выше. Это очень затратно.

Comment: Мне казалось проблема в динамических ключах, а не в рекурсивном переборе этого дерева

Comment: И в этом тоже. Конечно проще всего просто брать последний элемент динамического объекта, но их может быть много.

Comment: Насчет библиотек: https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/280782/ . У меня на работе используем [json-simple](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm) мне понравилась эта либа

Comment: jsonPath Вам в помощь